# How to initialize Bootstrap handlers after Ajax addition?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page that collects a set of user comments on the contents of that page.  New comments are added to the page by clicking a button and filling out a form that appears via a Bootstrap modal.  The results are then inserted into the page via ajax.  This is all working fine.

The "results" that are added to the page include another Bootstrap button/link, which looks something like this:

```
<a tabindex='-1' href='#' class='ajax-modal btn btn-small' 
      data-target='modal_my-modal' data-backdrop='true' 
      data-controls-modal='res-modal' data-keyboard='true' 
      url='/somewhere'>Click me</a>
```

The link looks and behaves like a button (thanks, Bootstrap!), but, when clicked, doesn't trigger the modal like it's supposed to.  However, if I refresh the page in the browser so that this comment, along with the others on the page, are redrawn, the button/link now works fine.

Since the button works when the page is redrawn, I'm assuming that there is some Bootstrap initialization code that runs when the page loads and sets up all the links to do their stuff, and that I need to call this after adding my new button to the page.  Is this correct, and, if so, what should I be calling to get the link properly initialized?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is indeed a function that gets called when the page is drawn and that sets up the click handlers -- it's my own function that's responsible for setting up the modals.  I added a call to that function after the html containing the button/link, and all's well.  I'm sure there is a Bootstrap init function that gets called, but calling my own is what was needed.